# What options allow me to properly step through code in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm trying to debug a pre-configured and optimized C++ project. I disabled "Optimization" under C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization. However when I step through code sometimes it jumps around randomly and often it doesn't show the proper values for local variables.

Comment: Projects usually have at least a debug and release config. Is there a debug config for you to use?

Comment: You probably need to have debug information as well as disabling optimization (which you have already applied). In addition, have you rebuilt the code after disabling optimization?

Comment: @NeilKirk The debug config in this project does not compile. That's why I'm basically trying to figure out what options to change so that this Release config behaves like a Debug config.

Comment: I would find out why debug mode doesn't compile first..

Comment: @NeilKirk This is a huge project for work that's been in development for more than a decade. Making it compile in debug is out of the question. That's why I'd rather mess around with the options.

Comment: For a project that's taken 10 years I would say not being able to compile in debug mode is out of the question. There must be something seriously wrong with the code.

Comment: What are the other optimization settings in that window?

Comment: @NeilKirk My guess is that many of the libraries that the project is linking to do not have a debug version available.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need a build with optimisations switched off and debug info being generated. I assume you're already generating a PDB for your release build.

The key here that there is no 'debug mode' - just different project settings. So it's possible (likely even) that while *some* of the settings in the debug config cause your build to fail, *others* (possibly including switching off optimisations and enabling debug info) may work fine.

I suggest you experiment with changing the properties **one at a time**. It's likely that you can take your working config, switch off optimisations, and it'll build fine. If so, you can keep the modified vcproj for yourself or create a new project config containing the changes, to share with your colleagues.

(sorry, not enough rep to post as comment)